# How can I restrict azure AD access from specific browsers?

Tags: reactjs, azure, active-directory, identity

how are you?
I made a small React App and connected it to my Azure AD account, so I can have an identity provider and log in for my Application .
Now, I need to be able to access my application ONLY with the chrome browser, and if I try to access it with Firefox or Edge It will deny the access. I have been playing with the Conditional access policies in my Azure account, but I was unable to find anything to help me out here.
Anyone know if this can be done and how? It is important to Clarify that I need this done using the Azure AD only, not using any other tool.
If not anyone knows of an identity provider that may be able to do this?
Thanks and I appreciate any advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   Yes, you can surely restrict the access from specific browser through Azure AD, but you will have two options with regards to this, viz., **restrict all the users with no specific Azure AD role to access the Azure AD portal completely through any browser completely** or **use the custom ADMX templates for ‘Google chrome’ specifically to allow a specific list of URLs and block others and similarly vice versa to allow only access to Azure AD portal through chrome browser.**

a)  To go ahead with the first option, **you will have to login to the Azure AD portal with the Azure AD role of ‘Azure AD Administrator’ or Azure role assignment of ‘Owner’**. Once logged in, then browse to the **‘User settings --> Administration Portal --> Restrict access to Azure AD administration portal --> Yes --> Save’**. Once, these settings are done, only **administrators will be allowed to access the Azure AD Administration portal while the ‘non-administrators’ will not** as shown below in the snapshot: -

[image: Azure AD Administration portal]

b)  For the second option, you will **need to have ‘Microsoft Intune’ license along with Azure AD Premium P1 or P2 license so that you are able to import the required custom policy ADMX templates for ‘Google chrome’ browser so that the specified list of URLs and websites are allowed for ‘Google chrome’ and blocked for all other browsers**.

For that purpose, **ensure that all the browser apps that are used by the people in your organization in Azure AD domain joined or registered devices are imported to Intune portal as ‘Desktop Apps’** through the options as shown below in the Intune portal: -

[image: Apps import to Intune]

Once done, then **create ‘App protection policies’ for the browser desktop apps that are imported earlier as shown below and configure the list of allowed URLs and sites for these apps** as shown below in the snapshot: -

[image: App protection policy]

Once the above have been configured, then **ensure to create an ‘App Configuration Policy’ as shown below to allow or block URLs accordingly on the ‘Managed apps’ category** as shown below in the snapshot: -

[image: App Configuration policy]

For more information regarding this, kindly refer to the below links: -

***https://blog.hametbenoit.info/2020/05/13/intune-manage-allowed-blocked-websites-for-microsoft-edge-on-mobile-devices/***

***[https://www.alitajran.com/restrict-access-azure/#:~:text=Click%20on%20the%20Menu%20and,Click%20Save.](https://www.alitajran.com/restrict-access-azure/#:%7E:text=Click%20on%20the%20Menu%20and,Click%20Save.)***

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed information, I will play around with these configurations, but it is definetly what I needed.